# Getting started with PopoverView and Display Item on Label in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am making a sample application where I am  using `UIPopoverView` to display the list of items.

I am following [this link](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development) for my sample application.

In the above link tutorial, a "movies list" appears. When the button is clicked, a pop over appears,but when I select the movie name it is not getting displayed on label.

can anyone tell what is happening or anything should be added in the code. I am not able to display the selected items on the label.

Comment: you need to post some code code or upload the project to get a definitive answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the connections of buttons and the respective actions. Debug the code placing the break point. I think u have missed something from the tutorial.

Comment: i checked everything is proper but still its not displaying..I think something is missing in the code

Answer (score 0):

print the string whatever you are selecting .And print the label text also.Check whether you are getting the strings correctly or not.So that you came to know where the mistake is.